Adding multiple instances of the same image into XLSX file using Openpyxl
I have a task to automate the generation of reports in Excel.
One of the features of this report is that it is necessary to add pictures of products, the same ones several times on different sheets.
When the manager made this report manually, they just copied the pictures from sheet to sheet and the size of the report was not very large.
When I started to automate this report in python + openpyxl, I faced the problem that I can't add the same picture twice - if I try to save this xlsx file, an error pops up:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
I got around this problem by reopening the image file each time, but this led to the problem that the xlsx file now has many instances of the same image, which bloats the file size.
Is it possible to add the same picture to different sheets via openpyxl without creating copies and bloating the size of the final file?

@moken Openpyxl is necessary because I am filling an existing xlsx template file. There are some formatting already done there manually, which I don't want to reproduce with code if I use e.g. XLSXWriter to create xlsx from scratch.

With Openpyxl, possibly not. When you save the workbook an image is closed after first use save to the Excel file. So a second save will tell you the image file is already closed. This is part of the saving process so you could only change that by changing the Openpyxl code. If you change things so the image is not recognised as physically the same at the different locations, the IO error wont occur but the result has to be that each image will be saved as a separate file within Excel. For other options is Openpyxl absolute necessity, notwithstanding the rest of your code is using that module?

But you do say "I am filling an existing xlsx template file". You're not able to add the images on/for all the Sheets in the template so the images don' need to be added when filling it in? Otherwise you could open the Openpyxl completed file in Xlwings after and add [all] the images with that module... Xlwings should not have this issue but needs Excel to work so the environment has a few more restrictions than Openpyxl.

Unfortunately, Excel will not be available on the machine where it is being deployed because this script is planned to be used in a web service. I'll have to check with the IT team, but I assume that it will be a Linux virtual machine. If it was not such a limitation, I would use, say, PyWin32API.
